# how to add group field in @Query annotation in Solr

Tags: java, solr, solrj, spring-data-solr

I have added a method to get quarters my repository class based on the value of book and year

`public interface Repository extends SolrCrudRepository<Doc, Long> {
    @Query(fields = { Constants.QUARTER_FIELD })
    public List<CodingClinicDoc> findQuarterByBookAndYear(String book, int year);
}`

but i am getting duplicate values e.g. 'First quarter' around 10 times

Please tell me if there is a way to apply group field like `group=true&group.field=quarter` to `@Query` annotation to get unique result.
Or some other way to get the distinct quarters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of version 1.5.2 of Spring Data Solr, you cannot use result grouping with SolrRepository. You'll have to use SolrTemplate. 
See this section (http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/solr/docs/1.5.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#solr.misc.group) on Spring data solr reference.